# EditView in ListView row: focus lost when soft keyboard shows

Tags: android

I have some EditViews in the rows of a ListView.  This works just fine except when the soft keyboard raises and lowers.

When I touch the EditView within the ListView with the soft keyboard down, focus jumps to the EditView, then the keyboard comes up, removes focus from the EditView and sets focus to the ListView, resulting in an odd user experience with the focus no-where visible.

Touching the EditViews with the keyboard already showing works as you would expect.  The problem seems to be with the soft keyboard lowering and raising and the ListView getting confused about where focus should be placed.

I do have listView.setItemsCanFocus(true) for the ListView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `android:focusable="false"` on the `ListView`.

Comment: This works well for the effect I'm going for.  I hadn't thought to remove it for the ListView!  It does have an odd effect in the 1.6 SDK in that if there are two EditText in the same row, selecting the second puts focus on the first when the keyboard goes from lowered to raised, but it is a big improvement!

Comment: I spoke too soon, this doesn't behave as expected.  With focusable set to false, when the keyboard comes up the focus is stolen from the EditText and given to the ListView, which in turn gives it to the first child control that accepts focus (the first EditText in the listView in my case, regardless of which EditText caused the soft keyboard from showing).  Somehow the ListView needs to keep track of the last child with focus and return the focus to it.  I guess I will have to dig into the ListView source some more.